# AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'core.User' that has not been installed

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I hope you are very well.
Since a few hours ago I have an error in extending the "User" model of Django, this with the intention of adding some fields for different users.

To extend the model I relied on two main sources:

The Django repository on Github - https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py

and from a Blog - simpleisbetterthancomplex - https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#abstractbaseuser

**Django version = 2.1**

At the time of running the command - ***python manage.py makemigrations***, I got the following error:

***"AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '% s' that has not been installed"% settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'core.User' that has
not been installed***

When wanting to define in settings.py - AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core.User'

And yes, I have an application called "core" that is already in the INSTALLED_APPS

**settings.py**

```
import os
from decouple import config
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', cast=bool)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = config('ALLOWED_HOSTS', cast=lambda v: [s.strip() for s in v.split(',')])

# Application definition

DJANGO_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
]
LOCAL_APPS = [
    'core',
    'users',
    'company',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS

# custome user model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core.User'

# Argon2 password hash
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
]
.......
```

**core/models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.utils import timezone

from .managers import UserManager
from .validators import UnicodeUsernameValidator

# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    An abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with
    admin-compilant permissions

username and password are required, other fields are optional.
"""
username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

username = models.CharField(
    _('Username'),
    max_length=150,
    unique=True,
    help_text=_('Required: 150 Characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
    validators=[username_validator],
    error_messages={
        'unique': _('A user with that username already exists.')
    },
)
email = models.EmailField(_('Email Address'), unique=True)
first_name = models.CharField(_('First name'), max_length=50, blank=True)
last_name = models.CharField(_('Last name'), max_length=60, blank=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(
    _('Staff stauts'),
    default=False,
    help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
)
is_active = models.BooleanField(
    _('Active'),
    default=False,
    help_text=_(
        'Designates whether this user should be treaged as active'
        'unselect this instead of deleting accounts'
    ),
)
is_company = models.BooleanField(_('User company permissions'), default=False)
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

objects = UserManager()

EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'username']

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('user')
    verbose_name_plural = _('users')
    abstract = True

def clean(self):
    super().clean()
    self.email = self.__class__.objects.normalize_email(self.email)

def get_full_name(self):
    """
    Return the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between
    """
    full_name = '%s %s' %(self.first_name, self.last_name)
    return full_name.strip()

def get_short_name(self):
    """
    Return the short name for the user
    """
    return self.first_name

def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Send an email to this user
    """
    send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

the ident in the code is fine but, here not haha

**core/apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'core'
```

Comment: Have you try this `LOCAL_APPS = [
    'core.apps.AppConfig',
    ...
]`

Comment: This give an error - 'core.apps.AppConfig' must supply a name attribute. - :/ I was trying to solve this around 8 hrs or more hahaha

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, finally I've the answer, in my class User.... in meta code we need to remove **abstract = True** and all works!

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('user')
    verbose_name_plural = _('users')
    abstract = True
```

to

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('user')
    verbose_name_plural = _('users')
```